# Preimage of discontinuous function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is defined by
\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,\quad x=1,\\
0,\quad x\in[0,1).
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I want to find $f^{-1}(U)$ for any open set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But, I find difficulties when I try to do that.
This is what I have done so far.

Let $(a,b)$ be any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$.
**Case I:** if $a<b<0$, then $f^{-1}((a,b))=\emptyset$.
**Case II:** if $a<0<b$, then
\begin{align}
f^{-1}((a,b))=f^{-1}((a,0))\cup f^{-1}([0,b))=f^{-1}([0,b))
\end{align}
because $f^{-1}((a,0))=\emptyset$. Then, for $f^{-1}([0,b))$, I divided it into two cases again,
if $b\leq 1$, then $f^{-1}([0,b))=[0,1)$,
if $b>1$, then $f^{-1}([0,b))=f^{-1}([0,1))\cup f^{-1}([1,b))=[0,1)\cup\{1\}=[0,1]$.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}((a,b))=\begin{cases}
[0,1),\quad b\leq 1,\\
[0,1],\quad b>1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
**Case III:** if $0<a<b$, I divided it into two cases again,
if $b\leq 1$, then $f^{-1}((a,b))=\emptyset$,
if $b>1$, then $f^{-1}((a,b))=\{1\}$.

Is it correct? Or there are another various possible preimages that I missed?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you making it too complicated? There are four possible preimages, depending on whether $U$ contains $0$, or $1$, or both, or none of them.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, I think so. Because it is first time for me to find  preimage of a discontinuous function. But after read your comment and the answer below, I start to understand that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it really easy?

$f^{-1}(U)=\begin{cases}\emptyset& \quad: U\subset \Bbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}\\ [0,1)&\quad : 0\in U\subset \Bbb{R}\setminus \{1\}\\ \{1\} &\quad :1\in U \subset \Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}\\ [0, 1]&\quad : \{0,1\}\subset U\end{cases}$

Comment: Nice, I think your answer summarize what I write above. Let me strengthen my understanding. So, if I have a function $g:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 2, \, x<5\\ 6,\,x\geq 5\end{cases}$$ then possible preimages of open set $U$ are depending on $U\subset\mathbb{R}-\{2,6\}$, $\{2,6\}\subset U$, $2\in U\subset \mathbb{R}-\{6\}$, and $6\in U\subset \mathbb{R}-\{2\}$, right?

Comment: Exactly. You are absolutely right.